# excel vba range.find not finding date

Tags: excel, date, find, runtime-error, vba

I'm trying to establish the minimum date and its associated row for later use in a subroutine.

I'm hitting an error and i've spent the last few hours isolating the issue and searching for the solution to no avail.

I have a spreadsheet where `column B` contains a range of dates arranged in order. I can find the minimum date (the message box correctly returns 11/14/2015), but when I try use that date value to identify the row number I get error 91. Here is my code:

```
    Sub testing()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Burn Curve Data").Activate

    Dim rDateColumn As Range
    Dim dMinDate As Date
        Set rDateColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B")
        dMinDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rDateColumn)

    MsgBox dMinDate

    Dim rMinCell As Range
    Dim intMinRow As Integer
        Set rMinCell = rDateColumn.Find(dMinDate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        intMinRow = rMinCell.Row

    MsgBox intMinRow

    End Sub
```

I tried inserting an `If Not` statement after `Set rMinCell` and determined that `range.find` is not finding the date. Here is the statement I used to identify the error, but I deleted it to clean up the code for this posting.

```
    If Not rMinCell is Nothing Then
        intMinRow = rMinCell.Row
    Else
        MsgBox "error finding rMinCell"
    End If
```

I also tried re-saving `dMinDate` into a string then using that string in the `range.find` but I encountered the same error of not finding the date.

Another nuance that may or may not be relevant is that this data exists within a named range on the worksheet. What am I doing wrong with my `range.find` line?!?

Comment: If the dates are arranged in order, why bother finding the min and searching for it at all? If you know the order of the dates, just take the first or last cell in the range, depending on how it is sorted

Comment: there are cells with other information above and below these dates in `column B`.  i will also be using `dMinDate` as a default value in a userform. users will use this form when they want to change the beginning and end dates of this date range. people here can't be relied upon to properly copy/insert new lines with formulas in them.

Comment: No problem.  Are the dates in column B properly formatted as dates (right click --> Format Cells and ensure 'Date' is selected under Category) ?  I did a quick test and if the formatting wasn't a date I got the error 91 that you are getting.  You might add the code `rDateColumn.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"` after setting the variable and seeing if that helps.

Comment: If you get error 91 instead of getting the message provided by your errorhandler... that means you're actually entering the ` If Not rMinCell is Nothing Then intMinRow = rMinCell.Row ` ? Am I correct in this assumption?

Comment: AAARRRGGGGHHHHH!!! you were right.

Comment: the column format was set to custom---> "mm/dd" because it is the x-axis of a chart and i needed the shortened date format for a cleaner display. thank you Joshua.

Comment: david i'm sorry i was unclear... the error handler was returning my error message, not error 91.

Comment: @JoshuaRoss how do I mark your comment as the answer? I can post the answer myself, but I don't want to hurt your street cred ;)

Comment: Thank you kindly!  Let me answer the question for you, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments it appears the issue arises when the column is formatted as something other than `Date`.

To do this via code you can add this line after you set the `rDateColumn` variable:

```
rDateColumn.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
```

This should format the column as a date and your `Find` method should work appropriately.

Alternatively you can select the column, click 'Format Cells' and then ensure 'Date' is selected under Category.